# Removing elements from arrays with specific content(special characters)

Tags: php, arrays

Request your help to remove empty array elements, I tried `array_filter` and `array_map('array_filter', $array)` but nothing seem to be working as expected. Below is the array structure and the expected output,

**Original Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [
    [1] =>     [
    [2] =>         [
    [3] =>             "Test",
    [4] =>             "Server1",
    [5] =>             null,
    [6] =>             "Server2",
    [7] =>             null,
    [8] =>             "",
    [9] =>             "stopped",
    [10] =>         ]
    [11] =>     ]
    [12] => ]
)
```

**Expected Array output**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>             "Test",
    [1] =>             "Server1",
    [2] =>             null,
    [3] =>             "Server2",
    [4] =>             null,
    [5] =>             "",
    [6] =>             "stopped",
)
```

Note the `null` and `""` elements should not be removed.

Comment: by the looking at your example, they are nester array with 1 element, thus they are not empty. maybe just create a new array with the elements you find ?

Comment: How did you end up with an array like your input?

Comment: Can you edit your post with your code?

Comment: The output array is from the aws cli command execution via PHP exec

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function for checking each element on `[` or `]` existance:

```
preg_match ('/[\[\]]+/', $val, $matches);
```

If it has - skip this value. So, if your input array has a structure like:

```
$ar = Array
(
    0 => "[",
    1 => "    [",
    2 => "       [",
    3 =>             "Test",
    4 =>             "Server1",
    5 =>             null,
    6 =>             "Server2",
    7 =>             null,
    8 =>             "",
    9 =>             "stopped",
    10 =>  "       ]",
    11 =>  "   ]",
    12 => "]",
);
```

This function will remove corresponded elements:

```
function cleanArray($ar){ 
    $res = [];
    foreach($ar as $val){ 
        preg_match ('/[\[\]]+/', $val, $matches); 
        if(count($matches) == 0) $res[] = $val;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8F1BI)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) with a pattern that matches a single `[` or `]` and use the flag `PREG_GREP_INVERT` to get the inverted match.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iVSBMi/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/76RpE)

```
^\h*[][]\h*$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `[][]` [Character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), match either `[` or `]`
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

For example

```
$array = Array
(
    "[",
    "     [",
    "         [",
    "Test",
    "Server1",
    null,
    "Server2",
    null,
    "",
    "stopped",
    "         ]",
    "     ]",
    "]"
);

$res = preg_grep("/^\h*[][]\h*$/", $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
var_export($res);
```

Output

```
array (
  3 => 'Test',
  4 => 'Server1',
  5 => NULL,
  6 => 'Server2',
  7 => NULL,
  8 => '',
  9 => 'stopped',
)
```

If you want to reset the keys in the resulting array, you could use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) `array_values($res)`

Answer (score -1):

For this specific format you can use this:

```
$array =  [
 [
     [
         "Test",
         "Server1",
         null,
         "Server2",
         null,
         "",
         "stopped",
     ]
 ]
];

// array_shift needs to receive value by reference, or it throws notice
$shifted_array = array_shift($array); 
$inner_array = array_shift($shifted_array);

echo "<pre>";
   die(var_dump(  $inner_array  ));
echo "</pre>";

// output

array (size=7)
  0 => string 'Test' (length=4)
  1 => string 'Server1' (length=7)
  2 => null
  3 => string 'Server2' (length=7)
  4 => null
  5 => string '' (length=0)
  6 => string 'stopped' (length=7)
```

Answer (score -2):

> The array_filter() function filters elements or values of an array using a callback function. if no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE will be removed.
>
> print_r(array_filter($array));